# LINQ to check if class is in list

Tags: c#, json, linq

I've got a situation in which I have to handle adding custom objects in a list if they don't exist. So far I've got no luck.

I have a custom class called ImagePoint:

```
public class ImagePoint
{
    public List<string> Point { get; set; }
    public List<string> NameSize { get; set; }

    public ImagePoint(List<string> _Point, List<string> _NameSize)
    {
        Point = _Point;
        NameSize = _NameSize;
    }
}
```

I'm currently using JSON.NET to save and load my `ImagePoint` object. JSON saves the file with the output which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Point": [
      "16 11"
    ],
    "NameSize": [
      "Preview Buttons",
      "27 11"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Point": [
      "16 0"
    ],
    "NameSize": [
      "Close Buttons",
      "27 11"
    ]
  }
]
```

I read the file and load the contents into my `imagePointsList':

```
List<ImagePoint> imagePoint = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ImagePoint>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
foreach (var item in imagePoint)
{
    imagePointsList.Add(item);
}
```

Now Before I want to add I first make a new ImagePoint object and assign the values to it like so:

```
string[] p, s;
ImagePoint image_point = new ImagePoint(new List<string>(), new List<string>());
image_point.NameSize.Add(tb_point_name.Text);

if (tb_position.Text.Contains(",")) //More than one Point
{
    p = tb_position.Text.Split(',');
    image_point.Point.AddRange(p);
}
else // One Point
{
    p = new string[1];
    p[0] = tb_position.Text;
    image_point.Point.AddRange(p);
}

if (tb_width_height.Text.Contains(",")) //More than one Size
{
    s = tb_width_height.Text.Split(',');
    image_point.NameSize.AddRange(s);
}
else // One Size
{
    s = new string[1];
    s[0] = tb_width_height.Text;
    image_point.NameSize.AddRange(s);
}
```

Then I check if the contents are the same using:

```
bool contains = imagePointsList.Any(item => item.Point.ToArray() == p);
```

Problem is that even when I load the json file and I know those points exist in the list (see the json output) I still get a False value from `contains` variable.

How can I efficiently check if list already has an item with the values p, if it does should `contains` should return True else False.

Comment: `==` compares refereces on arrays, try `item.Point.SequenceEqual(p)`

Comment: As the previous comment says, you shouldn't compare objects like that with the (==) operator as it compares references (except on value types). You could use the SequenceEqual method, though you do another LINQ expression on your item.Point.ToArray(), in which you check if all values in that array are also in p using the same construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` compares references of arrays not their content, try `item.Point.SequenceEqual(p)`:

```
bool contains = imagePointsList.Any(item => item.Point.SequenceEqual(p));
```

Comment: Or even better: override `Object.Equals(object)` inside `ImagePoint` and compare with `item.Equals(p)`.

Comment: @Abbondanza: if that's what OP wants. I'm not sure because ImagePoint contains  another list `NameSize`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter why does `bool contains = imagePointsList.Any(item => item.Point.SequenceEqual(p) && item.NameSize.SequenceEqual(s));` return False? what If I want to check for p and s?

Comment: @F4z: depends on what "check" actually means. If you want to know if all strings are equal to all others in another list/array and that applies to both lists, then this should work. If only one of both need to be equal use `||`. But does the order matter at all? `SequenceEqual` returns false if the order is different.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Similar to p and how if there is an item in the `imagePointsList with the same values as p then return false.

Comment: Actually I got it to work, problem with the way I was comparing them both.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` variable will never be true because when you write `item.Point.ToArray()` .Net creates a new array, and then it compares it. But arrays doesn't have overloaded equality operator, thus they will be compared by reference. Because `ToArray()` just created a new array, it will never happen. You can use `SequenceEqual` from LINQ namespace or write your own comparer. And be careful with `ToArray()` calls in cycles because it adds a lot of pressure on GC.